# How can I register The Witcher 2 and get the Troll Trouble DLC?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I just started up the game launcher and saw that the "Troll Trouble" DLC is free if you register the game.  If I try to register through the launcher menu, I get this error:

> Connection error. Try again later.

I also tried to register through the website, but both the Register and Login links in the top-right of the web page appear to be dead.  (If you view source, the CSS class is "inactive".)

Is there any way I can work around this?

**Edit:** Now I get the following error:

> A connection with the server could not be established.

So it definitely seems to be due to the work they're doing for the patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I just found [this](http://en.thewitcher.com/community/entry/27/).  I assume the "second downtime" is occurring now, and they haven't actually posted about it yet.

> We are currently updating the servers and preparing for the incoming patch release. We will be posting updates on this issue.
>
> **UPDATE:** The servers are up but we predict another downtime today. It shouldn't take more than an hour and we will inform about it.

**Edit:** I was able to register through the launcher later but still cannot sign into the website.  The only DLC available was the Polish voiceovers and subtitles, until I restarted the launcher. Troll Trouble was there and I am downloading it (just ignore the box asking you for a pre-order code and hit "Download").

You can get your preorder stuff using the info in [one of their blog posts](http://en.thewitcher.com/community/entry/34/) and you can patch the game using [this post](http://en.thewitcher.com/patch/) if it doesn't update automagically.

**Edit 2:** [Patch 1.2 is out](http://en.thewitcher.com/patch1-2/) and comes with all of the previous DLC.

Comment: Does this make my question Too Localized?

Comment: Assuming the problem goes away in a couple hours, yes.  You can delete it if that is the case.

Comment: Looks like issues persist, I'll try to keep this answer somewhat current to help other people.